# combine datetimepicker and moment for Min date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, date, momentjs

I have combine datetimepicker and moment-timezone-with-data.js
I could not wind how to set mindate set after 1 day and mintime after 4 hour
is any specific function with moment 
Please help me with this code

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="label-control">Datetime Picker</label>
<input type="text" id='datetimepicker1' class="form-control"/>
</div>  
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var mind = moment.tz("Asia/Dhaka").format();
        var Date = moment.tz("Asia/Dhaka").format();
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'en-gb',
            timeZone: 'Asia/Dhaka',
            defaultDate: Date,
            maxDate: mind,
            format: "DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm A"
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what you're trying to do, but I think you're looking for the [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) function.

```
moment().add({ days: 1, hours: 4 });
```